# плагин edu java для intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, плагин

Подскажите, как начать работу с плагином edu java в ИДЕЕ? Плагин скачан и отмечен в настройках. Как запустить проект с разделением на экраны и со списком заданий?

Comment: В решении этого вопроса вам поможет это видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMz9ZuFvZBk.